# Android Studio not including SDK or accepting downloaded SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

When I download Android Studio, it does not include the Android SDK anywhere (appdata, Android Studio, project files etc...). On launch, says "Please provide the path to SDK". I download the SDK tools separately, and it does not accept them.

Comment: Did you download from here? (https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads)

Comment: Please check if there is any white space in your SDK location.

Comment: Yep, installed it from that url.

 I saw this solve the problem for others but sadly no whitespace in my sdk download location. I tried /Android, /Android/tools, and /Android/tools/bin, none are accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual the second you ask for help, you figure it out... after being stuck for days.

Double shift -> SDK manager -> Edit path -> It will (hopefully) show an SDK components setup, where it finally installed everything I needed in the right places.

Not sure why the SDK was never installed on my machine and it rejected the separately installed sdk, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio ==> Click on SDK Manager (Box icon with a down arrow in the center) ==> Update your SDK location in `Android SDK location`.

Comment: When I try updating the SDK location to where I downloaded the sdk tools, it doesnt accept it, gives me "SDK does not contain any platforms"

Comment: Can you provide the complete location ?

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio -> Double Tap Shift Key -> Search for Android SDK Location .

You will be directed to place where you need to set the path.

Select from the folder where you have downloaded separately.

Path should Drive Name:\Folder where you have downloaded\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: Even though I just did a fresh install of Android Studio, there is no Android SDK under AppData (or anywhere else)
When I try updating the SDK location to where I downloaded the sdk tools, it doesnt accept it, gives me "SDK does not contain any platforms"

Comment: Do you see platform folder inside AppData folder?